# What does "Not appointed to them" mean?

Tags: grammar

> "Kate, this isn't something that I dreamed up myself. I don't have the authority to hire advisors or authorize joint agency missions, or fly agents from Air Force bases. Are you understanding me? These decisions are made far from here by officials elected to office, *not appointed to them*."

Please give me some idea... (the way I know about the last sentence, *not appointed to them* is *not relevant to mention their name*).

Comment: An official in a democracy may be *elected* or *appointed*.  Generally, elected officials have more freedom to do as they wish.

Comment: In the US government the people in the top offices, the President and Congress, are **elected** to their offices, and are answerable only to the public. Lower officials are **appointed** to their offices, directly or indirectly, by the elected officials, they are answerable to the elected officials, and they carry out the policies decided by the elected officials.

Comment: @HotLicks The officials in the US government with the most freedom to do as they wish are arguably federal judges, and they're all appointed.

Comment: @deadrat - I said *generally*, and I was speaking of democracies in general.  (And federal judges have remarkable little freedom to do what they want -- they have to wait for the case to come to them, they have to depend on the Executive to carry out their decisions, and they are always under threat of impeachment from Congress.)

Comment: @HotLicks Not been in a federal court recently, I see.  There, the joke is "What's the difference between God and a federal judge?  Answer:  God doesn't think he's a federal judge"  Yes, they have to abide by the separation of powers, but so do the other branches.  Yes, they have to depend on the executive to carry out their orders, but I think the last time that didn't happen was due to Andrew Jackson.  Yes, they can be impeached, but there have been over 3K federal judges (and justices) over about 220 years.  8 have been removed from office by conviction upon impeachment.

Answer (score 1):

> These decisions are made far from here by officials elected to office, not appointed to them.

means that the decisions in question are made by those who are elected to office, not those appointed to office, where *appointed* means selected by other officials to hold office.

The quote is from the movie *Sicario*, about an FBI agent on an inter-agency joint task force, so this is about the US government.  This is an odd statement to make because generally, the operational details of the actions  of US governmental entities are made by appointed officials.  In fact, it's easy to count the elected officials in the US government -- two from the executive branch -- the President and the Vice President -- and at most 541 from the legislative branch -- 100 Senators (excluding those appointed by state officials to fill vacated Senate seats), 435 Representatives (excluding those appointed by state officials to fill vacated House seats), and 6 not voting Representatives from US territories.  That's it -- judicial branch officials are all appointed.  Since legislative officials are not allowed to perform executive actions, we're left the the President and the Vice-President.

Now, *Sicario* is fiction, and nothing says that fiction must conform to reality or that characters have to tell the truth about the plot, but perhaps the character speaking is implying that he reports to *very* high levels.

Comment: Hi, deadrat. I've just read your answer because the question has just been close-voted by a user. I have a quick question. Doesn't **them** mean **officials elected to office**? I mean the speaker is just appointed to serve *officials elected to office* and *officials elected to office* seems to mean President and Vice President, the highest position in the government who can make such a decision like flying agents from Air Force bases. Would appreciate your thought.

Comment: @Rathony I don't think so.  I think the sentence means "officials elected to office, not appointed to office."  Two reasons.  First *appointed to [something]* means selected for some position.  We don't say *appointed to someone*; we might say (as you did) "appointed to serve someone."  It would be odd to say that the National Security Advisor is appointed to the President.  He's appointed by the President to the National Security Council.  Second, the usual contrast is between offices of electoral authority and offices of delegated authority.

Comment: I see. The pronoun **them** made me confused. Thanks.

Comment: @Rathony You're right:  the plural pronoun seeks a plural antecedent, and the closest one is *officials*, but I think the sense goes with *office* as a collective.  If the phrasing had been "any officials elected to **an** office, not appointed to them," I'd have to go with your interpretation.